# How can I get the substatus code of the exception with java script? like 500.1

Tags: javascript, exception

I would like to read the substatus code of the exception like 500.1 on the client side. How to achieve this?

here is my code on the server side:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmail)) {                    
   Response.StatusCode = 500;
   Response.SubStatusCode = 1; 
   Response.StatusDescription = "Email fehlt";

   return;                    
}
```

Client side:

```
if (xhr.status == 500 && thrownError.indexOf("Email") > -1) {
    alert('Email is missing...');
}
else {
    alert('Error...');
}
```

Comment: `SubStatusCode` is never included in the actual response (used mainly for failed requests tracing and customized error pages). If you instist, you can implement a  global filter that will explicitly attach it to the response though. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.substatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Failed requests tracing - this is what I looking for.  I would like to return the Substatus exactly for specific failed requests, together with error status = 500 internal server error.

Comment: That's not what I meant by "Failed Request Tracing". I referred to the IIS module: https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis However, if you insist on attaching it to the actual response, I can write an answer that will provide the solution.

Comment: no thanks, I need  to send the substatus from the server side with c# and catch it with java script, without additional IIS configuration..

Comment: Add it to some header then. Something like `Response.AddHeader("error-sub-status", Response.SubStatusCode.ToString());`

Answer (score 1):

On client side you can use the `getAllResponseHeaders()` method of `XMLHttpRequest`.

If a correct http header is really sent, it will read it.

Example:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "ajax.php", true);
request.send();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
        console.log(this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    }
}
```

Output is separated by "\r\n".

If somehow the substatus cannot go through, maybe you can use another http header field for your goal, even if it is not according to the standards...

Comment: Reading the headers would not suffice as by default the sub-status code is not part of the response. Unless you'll explicitly add it to the response somehow, it would simply not be there for you to read.